# How to redirect a link address (from 3rd party site) to address of my choosing

Tags: redirect, hyperlink

I am looking for a program, or add-on, app, or Anything really, that will allow me to make it so that when one clicks on a certain link, this program redirects the click to go to a website of my choice.  Only on the computer with the program installed.

So like, take the "Home" button up top.  I would like to be able to do something like this with it:
0. install this program on my machine
1. Right-click and copy link address
2. plug this address into the program
3. plug in the address to redirect to
4. when someone on my machine clicks the link with the original address (in 1.) it now is redirected to go to the new address (3.)

Does anyone know of ANY thing for a computer that can do this? I have searched for days, and only found code/script for websites that I created. (I know this is a primarily coding website, but I could not find anywhere else to ask with smart enough computer-savvy people who might know an answer)

Thank you SO much for all your help.  You have no idea how much this will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a proxy, sounds pretty malicious however.

Comment: How would I go about doing this with a proxy?

I am a noob at this.  And it is not for me to do any Black-Hat style malicious hacking or anything haha.  I want to do this so when I  click a link on a site I go to all the time (or when a friend clicks it when my laptop is playing music), that it redirects the click to a different site so that my settings and stuff will not get messed with while my computer is out in the open.

Answer (score 0):

Solved (after much personal research): use the 'Redirector' add-on for FireFox.  It does exactly what is requested above. Let's one take a link URL, and anytime one clicks on that link within FireFox, it may redirect to a link URL of the user's choice.